# Change Context path of .NET 6 application

Tags: .net, aws-api-gateway, .net-6.0, aws-fargate

I have a .NET 6 application that my client has asked me to deploy on AWS Fargate and expose via a Rest API Gateway.
I need to change the application context root to be `/<stage name>` instead of `/`
I have the following Dockerfile so far

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /WebAdmin
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ARG API_GATEWAY_STAGE_NAME
RUN echo "API_GATEWAY_STAGE_NAME is $API_GATEWAY_STAGE_NAME" 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp.Web.Admin/MyApp.Web.Admin.csproj", "MyApp.Web.Admin/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./MyApp.Web.Admin/./MyApp.Web.Admin.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp.Web.Admin"
RUN sed -i "s/~\//\/${API_GATEWAY_STAGE_NAME}\//g" ./Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
RUN more ./Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
RUN dotnet build "./MyApp.Web.Admin.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /WebAdmin/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./MyApp.Web.Admin.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /WebAdmin/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /WebAdmin
COPY --from=publish /WebAdmin/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.Web.Admin.dll"]
```

How can I go about changing the context root of the application via either the Dockerfile or in code?
I am running into issues where static assets such as images / css files are not coming back with the correct path and causing errors.
The client does not have a DNS I can use yet so a Custom Domain Name is out of the question for now.
Any assistance on how I can change the context path to have the application running for a demo would be much appreciated